# Xamarin GeoLocatorPlugin change minDistance during runtime

Tags: xamarin, location, geofencing

in my xamarin-App I need Geofencing.

I'm using [GeoLocatorPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin).

Is there a way to influence the parameter "minDistance" at runtime (after start listening)?

```
await StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), "minDistance");
```

Background:
I want to optimize the interval for "position updates(changes)" depending on given "points of interest" (their distance to the users position).

Greetings and thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently getting the time and distance by a web service(i don't now your case but you can do something very similar to this), and i save like this(Local storage of the device):

```
  dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(responseString);
                Application.Current.Properties["gps_distancia"] = obj.rssUser.gps_distancia;
                Application.Current.Properties["gps_tempo"] = obj.rssUser.gps_tempo;
```

And then i call the storage time and distance that came from the webservice and i saved in the device:

```
           int tempoWebService = Int32.Parse(Application.Current.Properties["gps_tempo"].ToString()); 
        int distanciaWebService = Int32.Parse(Application.Current.Properties["gps_distancia"].ToString()); 


        await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tempoWebService), distanciaWebService, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
        {
            ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
            AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
            DeferLocationUpdates = true,
            DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
            DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
            PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        });
```